# ... dates them immediately after >the< Sanabares >of the silver coins<

Tags: definite-article, prepositional-phrases

> There are two explanations for the copper archer-type coins. A.
>   Simonetta sees in them a Sanabares II, and dates them immediately
>   after ***the Sanabares (I)*** ***of the silver coins***. ([Source](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/42664548?uid=3739920&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106329281251))

To which part of the sentence "of the silver coins" refers?

Why "Sanabares (I)" takes "the"?

Comment: Your link is only a preview, which cuts your quote mid-sentence. Full thesis is available as PDF download at https://digitalcollections.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/11274/1/Dobbins_K.W._1972.pdf (found it by googling your quote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *of the silver coins* modifies *the Sanabares (I)*. The collocation may be paraphrased “the Sanabares (I) connected with the silver coins” —that is, the Sanabares who had those coins minted, whose name appears on them.
- This Sanabares, retrospectively and hypothetically identified as the first of that name, takes the definite article *the* because he has been previously identified in the article and its preceding literature: he is a Sanabares readers know about, as distinct from “a” second Sanabares who is introduced into the discourse for the first time in this sentence.